# Cartoon where a little kid controls a huge robot which used to be small toy using glove

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, robots, toys

I remember a poor kid (main lead) who can't afford that much studies which rich kid. He saw a toy and wants to play with it. The rich kid broke it and threw it away but he took it from the trash tries to repair it. Something happened and the robot becomes huge and does whatever the kid says, gives him a glove where it shows different mods of that robot in a circular holographic disk form. He uses it to fight aliens (I guess).

Answer (score 2):

*[Heroman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroman)*

> Orphaned American boy Joey lives with his grandmother, working at a restaurant in the West Coast city of Center City (センターシティ Sentā Shiti, based on Los Angeles), while going to school. Upon hearing of a new toy robot called the Heybo, Joey believes that getting one will make his life better, turning him into a hero to protect his friends and family. However, he cannot afford to buy it on his meager salary. His luck changes when he picks up a broken down Heybo abandoned by a school bully. He tries to fix it, naming it Heroman, but does not have any luck in getting it to work. However, when it gets struck by a bolt of strange lightning, it transforms into a giant robot, just in time to save his friend Lina from impending danger. Now, Joey and Heroman are Earth's only defense against the evil insectoid Skrugg (スクラッグ Sukuraggu) aliens, unknowingly summoned to Earth by Joey's science teacher.

Joey, Heroman, and Joey's circular glove, can be seen in the cover of the first issue of the manga:
[image: Title image of Heroman]

### Trailer

Found by searching for `anime poor kid giant toy robot` after searching for `cartoon poor kid giant toy robot` failed to get a good answer.

Comment: If this is your answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.