# Where can I find an English language version of Heroman?

Tags: heroman

How can I watch [*Heroman*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroman#Anime) episodes in English?

[image: Heroman poster]

Comment: Shopping questions are fine if the answer isn't trivially easy (e.g. "Try Amazon")

Comment: Does this mean that my answer to your other question was correct?

Comment: It appears that you've accidentally created duplicate accounts (c.f. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220292/cartoon-anime-where-thunder-hits-a-robot-and-the-boy-hero-can-then-control-it-to). You can merge them as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: This particular questions seems to be on topic per the first and last bullets of the [shopping questions policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/501/58193).

Answer (score 4):

It would appear that no (official) English dub of this series exists.

> Sam Pinansky, who officially translated the series for Crunchyroll, claims that prior to Japanese broadcast, animation giant Disney signed on to broadcast the show internationally, but that they pulled out last minute. An English-language pilot was produced by Wowmax Media for this attempt in Los Angeles, USA. The pilot was screened at Anime Expo 2010, but has never been seen since.
>
> As Disney invested in the production of the show, it's unlikely any other entity could license it out. Due to Heroman's failure in Japan and the time since its debut, it's also unlikely Disney will ever have a change of heart about its western potential.
>
> <sub><sup>[Heroman (lost English dub of anime series; 2012)](https://lostmediawiki.com/Heroman_(lost_English_dub_of_anime_series;_2012))</sup></sub>