# Pre '96 cartoon: boy remote controls white robot

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, robots

So this has haunted me for 20+ years. I turned on the television, ca 1995 I guess, and saw this cartoon where a male character, a teen I think, controls this huge white robot whith a joystick. The white robot is fighting a black robot. All the time the boy is yelling and screaming and as I remember it the boy also started crying, don't remember why.

I believe it was a cartoon made, late eighties - early nineties, but who knows.
I don't know if it was a movie or a TV show of some sort. But most probably a TV show.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Gigantor? I remember the kid had sort-of a box with one control on it, and he controlled this large robot with it. The robot was white or silver? But the original was much older than 1995.

Comment: @NomadMaker I so beleive you are quite spot on. I remeber coming across Gigantor in my search before. But as you pointed out its really old. But looking into it again they apparently released a remake in early 80s and that feels just about tight. Post as an anser and I will upvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241910/pre-96-cartoon-boy-remote-controls-white-robot#comment664052_241910) above, this may be [The New Adventures of Gigantor](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458218/). Sci-Fi Channel broadcast it from 1993 to 1997. It was converted from New Tetsujin-28, which aired on Nippon Television from 1980 to 1981.

Answer (score 1):

This may only be a partial match, since the boy controls the robot with an interface on his glove, not a joystick, but maybe *[Heroman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroman)* as per [Cartoon where a little kid controls a huge robot which used to be small toy using glove](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216499/cartoon-where-a-little-kid-controls-a-huge-robot-which-used-to-be-small-toy-usin/216504#216504)?

[image: Cover of Heroman]

> Orphaned American boy Joey lives with his grandmother, working at a restaurant in the West Coast city of Center City (センターシティ Sentā Shiti, based on Los Angeles), while going to school. Upon hearing of a new toy robot called the Heybo, Joey believes that getting one will make his life better, turning him into a hero to protect his friends and family. However, he cannot afford to buy it on his meager salary. His luck changes when he picks up a broken down Heybo abandoned by a school bully. He tries to fix it, naming it Heroman, but does not have any luck in getting it to work. However, when it gets struck by a bolt of strange lightning, it transforms into a giant robot, just in time to save his friend Lina from impending danger. Now, Joey and Heroman are Earth's only defense against the evil insectoid Skrugg (スクラッグ Sukuraggu) aliens, unknowingly summoned to Earth by Joey's science teacher.

### Trailer