# Anime/cartoon where the main character has a toy/model that turns humanoid and fights an alien invasion

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

Show about a male child main character that has a toy/model figure that turns into a humanoid robot similar to *Heroman*, but he produces electricity and fights aliens from space. The aliens force the mc and family to move to a shelter. The main character often goes to a Ferris wheel as his hideout/safe haven. I only remember that the robot had to save a dam once that made humanity question if it was truly bad since it was live broadcast. It's not sentient like Heroman where he can express himself. The military were also more prominent and give of a more believable response. It was probably 10-12 years ago, and that it had a darker tone to the art style where there was not much colour and story telling compared to Heroman. Also, the robot had a more plain design that had only gray. Sadly can't remember if mc had any remote control

-watch it on tv but not in america and I when trough scene from heroman and realise they had very similar scenarios but I remember a completely different art style and character so was there multiple  different production on heroman or am I tripping

Comment: Can you remember anything else about this? Why it’s fighting the aliens? Why the main character goes to a Ferris wheel? Any of the plot at all? When you watched this? If so please [edit] your question to include anything else you remember.

Comment: Does your edit mean that it's not *Heroman*? Can you please edit further to clarify how, as Heroman does have the fight against aliens and the electrical powers?

Comment: Anything in this [list of recommendations if one liked *Heroman*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/4334/Heroman/userrecs) rings a bell?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the "the human" trusting it? Do you mean the child main character? Humanity in general? And do you remember how he controls the robot? Is there a joystick? A cockpit? A watch that he speaks into?

Comment: :) Thanks for the clarification. Do you remember how the kid controls the robot? Was it a boy or a girl? Japanese? American? Black? Indian? And do you happen to remember how the kid controls the robot?

Answer (score 3):

*Heroman* (2010)?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroman):

> Orphaned American boy Joey lives with his grandmother, working at a restaurant in the West Coast city of Center City, while going to school. **Upon hearing of a new toy robot called the Heybo**, Joey believes that getting one will make his life better, turning him into a hero to protect his friends and family. However, he cannot afford to buy it on his meager salary. His luck changes when he picks up a broken down Heybo abandoned by a school bully. He tries to fix it, naming it Heroman, but does not have any luck in getting it to work. However, **when it gets struck by a bolt of strange lightning, it transforms into a giant robot**, just in time to save his friend Lina from impending danger. Now, **Joey and Heroman are Earth's only defense against the evil insectoid Skrugg aliens**, unknowingly summoned to Earth by Joey's science teacher. [...]
>
> Originally a broken down toy robot called Heybo, Heroman is brought to life by a strange bolt of lightning and turns into a giant robot (in the anime, this lightning is caused by the Skrugg fleet heading towards Earth). **He uses his powerful fists and electrical powers** to protect Earth from the Skrugg and other threats.

I don't know if they frequently go there, but here's an image of the main protagonists on a Ferris wheel:

[image: teenagers on a Ferris wheel]

---

Found by searching this site for `[story-identification] robot toy fight` which brought up [Cartoon where a little kid controls a huge robot which used to be small toy using glove](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/216499/) - I knew the plot sounded vaguely familiar.

Comment: If this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.